# htaccess, detect if starting with specific character

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, get

Currently I have my htaccess configured so that when I type anything after the domain, it is treated as a get

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1
```

so

> www.example.com/test

will redirect to

> www.example.com/index.php?id=test

now what I would like is the page to detect if after the first / there is the @ character and do something diffirent

for example,

> www.example.com/#test

goes to

> www.example.com/index.php?abc=test

whilst still retaining the first rule, can this be done?

And as a bonus, if you know how to use the # symbol instead of the @, please do let me know, I tried putting NE flag in my rule but I had no luck.

Comment: You can not rewrite urls with `#` symbol as `#` fregment is client side only and it is not sent to the server.

Comment: ok cheers, how would I then have @ symbol instead, whilst retaining the first rule for some circumstances